# Stockfish 6 in Chessmaster Grandmaster Edition

Tags: engines, software, chessmaster

Is their a way to install stockfish 6 in Chessmaster Grandmaster Edition ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use stockfish, you need GUI that supports UCI. I can suggest [Arena](http://www.playwitharena.com/) or [Scid vs. PC](http://scidvspc.sourceforge.net/) as good free GUIs. 
Chessmaster isn't capable of that.

Comment: As long as you download both stockfish and one of these guis, are you good to go?

Comment: @MattCremeens yes you are